# TD Intercept equation

Tags: python, math, intercept

I am writing this space tower defense game based on defending the planet . The guns have a 260 degree firing range, they also are orbiting the planet. 
the creeps can come in every direction (360 degrees around the planet).
I want the gun to smartly target the creep, aiming to where the bullet will hit the creep and not where the creep is.

I was wondering how to calculate where the bullet will intercept the alien.

Thanks in advance

Note:This is not homework nor is am i asking you to write code. I just don't understand the math to solve this problem.

These are the things i know: Creep's speed, creeps position, creeps destination, Bullets speed, bullets original position. I do not know any angles. 
I would show you a picture, but apparently i don't have enough reputation points

Currently i have it implemented that the bullet gets updated with the creeps position so the bullet bends with the creep. It's highly inefficient and not how i want it at all.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive

Comment: Either this is homework, or it's going to find itself in the first of a series of spaced based projectile weapons. Neither are strong motivations to help. (btw, if it is homework, tag it as such, and ask specific questions and people will still help).

Comment: Oh, my apologies, it missed the first sentence. Still, the bigger point by @InbarRose stands.

Comment: Not trying to get you to write code, i just don't understand the math- also would be great if i could show a picture to make it more clear, is there another way  to do that as i don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: [This sort of thing](http://www.phy.bris.ac.uk/webtutorials/) would seem a good place to start.

Comment: @InbarRose and closevoters: the poster didn't ask for any code. Their question is how to algorithmically approach the problem - what's wrong about that?

Comment: @thg435 and OP . StackOverflow is not a site to ask any question you want, that being said, if your question is not related to this site, then don't ask it here. If you want math help, go to http://math.stackexchange.com/ If you are asking a question here it is because you need programming help.

Comment: @InbarRose: The poster asked for an algorithm to solve the problem, that's positively on-topic here: [if your question generally covers... a software algorithm... then you're in the right place](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you get a system of two equations:
[image]
where `|XY|` is distance between two points. You must be able to solve that system and figure out the coordinates `Xp,Yp` of the intersection point. For more info:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance

Comment: The problem is i don't know the intersection point where the creep hits bullet. 
sorry for the bad asci art:

                       bullet
                       |     \

Comment: @Belrouk: looks like I misunderstood the question, see edit.